# jQUery UI 1.8 effect

Tags: jquery-ui

The team talks about one new effect released in jQUery UI 1.8. Which one is that and where can i read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://jqueryui.com/docs/Changelog/1.8a2, the new effect is fade. There appears to be source code at http://dev.jqueryui.com/browser/tags/1.8rc3/ui/jquery.effects.fade.js?rev=3856, as a start.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about it fade in the docs here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Fade